# Connecting river segments with R riverdist package

Tags: qgis, r, rivers

I have imported river courses from OpenStreetMap into QGIS in order to recreate the Rhine river system for analysis in R with the riverdist package.

In order to calculate distances between sampling spots the river segments should be connected, of course. I can check this with

```
topologydots(rivers=Rhine)
```

And see that many segments, well almost all, remain unconnected (red dots)

[image]

Using

```
cleanup(Rhine)
```

as suggested in the [riverdist tutorial](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/riverdist/vignettes/riverdist_vignette.html) asks me several questions but does not connect the river segments.

Do I have to connect these segments one by one in QGIS or is there any solution within the riverdist package?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have merged all rivers now in QGIS and it seems to work (with the disadvantage of course that segments now all have the same attribute).

[image]